# using subdomains on Cloud Run with nginx

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-run

The idea:

1. I want to run a static site deployed on NGINX server in Cloud Run.
2. This server is going to have two subdomains - basically, I want to have two domains assigned to one Cloud Run instance.

The reason for this is to have two slightly different sites within one container/cloud run instance (since they are only slightly different, having completely separate services does not seem sensible).

The problem:

Let's say I have two subdomains: sub1.example.com and sub2.example.com. I described them both in my nginx config, seemingly the config is correct - the server starts up in the container and I can even reach one of the subdomains (let's say sub1.example.com). When I try to access sub2.example.com though, I get a 500 error. I do not think it is an issue with my nginx config, because the logs show something strange (obviously all the project info has been edited out by me):

```
{
  "insertId": "63bfe64f00062b37157ff3d1",
  "httpRequest": {
    "requestMethod": "GET",
    "requestUrl": "http://sub2.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/yjin9yFmV0NlXspNoP1_vLRP-0UBONJGPtl61l5I_gPuUsubDg2o88NS1GO8oA_Q",
    "requestSize": "409",
    "status": 500,
    "responseSize": "814",
    "userAgent": "Google-Certificates-Bridge",
    "remoteIp": <remote-ip>,
    "serverIp": <server-ip>,
    "latency": "0.010053946s",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "service_name": "service-name",
      "location": "europe-west1",
      "project_id": "project-id",
      "configuration_name": "configuration-name",
      "revision_name": "revision-name"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-01-12T10:51:59.404279Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "0071bb48153ed55117f678f5d9609fe439a5eb69edd72da13aefdc58878f4c75f5b2345b96cf921b11f9f93e6833db2fa9339c9905b1de7ab8798984b4e121ca7f"
  },
  "logName": "projects/project-name/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests",
  "trace": "projects/project-name/traces/3548cd1a6ced04d963dc94419e208959",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-01-12T10:51:59.676145078Z",
  "spanId": "244873288111162464",
  "traceSampled": true
}
```

The question is - what exactly is going on and how do I deal with it to achieve the desired result?

My NGINX config, just in case:

```
server {
    listen $PORT;
    listen  [::]:$PORT;
    server_name sub1.example.com;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/sub1;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        index  index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/sub1;
    }
}

server {
    listen $PORT;
    listen  [::]:$PORT;
    server_name sub2.example.com;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/sub2;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
            index  index.html;
        }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/sub2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Moving our conversation here :) Basically it is possible to use different domains but both need to be mapped in the https://console.cloud.google.com/run/domains section. Once done, make sure you have: Correct certificates for both domains, Correct DNS rule pointing to the Cloud Run Load Balancer
More info: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains

Comment: Oh, okay, so it seems that I will have to wait out until my mapping finishes and then do something about the certificates. It is pretty strange though - my subdomains have not finished mapping (or whatever they are doing), but I am able to access my first subdomain on cloud run just fine.

Comment: yes it may take a while. Eventually, if the mapping is not possible because an issue with the SSL certificate, it will be displayed in the mapping section. Therefore, you should proceed with the certificate before having the mapping in place, otherwise google will give up retrying if it fails and you have to recreate the mapping.

Comment: Okay, I will try doing that first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up configuring a load balancer with certificates, the solution was basically to wait until DNS finishes its propagation and make appropriate certificates.
I also did not have to map anything in cloud run itself - I pointed both subdomains at my load balancer and configured routing to my app.
The error itself was silly enough - my second subdomain lacked an `index.html` and did not like that, throwing a 500 instead of 404.